# Painting splotches into a normal map?

Tags: normal-map

These splotches on the right are coming from this normal map and I cant figure out how.

[image]

I just learned how to bake procedural textures into the normal map but this looks painted in somehow?

I've tried using a black and white image texture. Painting splotches in and than plugging that through a normal map node and baking that to the normal map. (Same thing i've done with procedural textures)

I thought black and white would work beings that's what values the procedural textures use but its just not turning out.

Comment: your normal map is very pixellized, have you tried to bake onto a larger image in order to avoid this pixellisation?

Comment: This isn't my normal map, its an asset pulled from a game, specifically Fortnite. The normal map is alot bigger and this is just a small section Ive zoomed in on to get a better snapshot of where the splotches are coming from. As for the pixelation, In the UV Map, it looks like theyve just saved texture space for bigger more noticeable parts of the object.

Comment: oh ok it's the stretched splotches that are bothering you, could you please pack the images and share this particular object?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=SnVsrNgP" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/SnVsrNgP/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you push the contrast of your normal map you'll see the splotches you're talking about, you just need to paint on this part with the correct color in order to get rid of them (you can do it in Blender itself, if you use an image editor like Krita make sure that the image is *32-Bit Float*):

[image]

Comment: Ah I see, I wasn't trying to get rid of them, Just trying to figure out how it was done. So thank you! This was racking my brain for like an hour now.

Comment: yes it was hard to see